# Instantiate Singleton with ILogger before calling builder.Build()

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ilogger, .net-7.0

I have a .NET 7 application. I currently have the following code:

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
      .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
      .Build();

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Host.UseSerilog((hostContext, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration).Enrich.WithExceptionDetails().Enrich.WithDemystifiedStackTraces());

builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISettingsService, SettingsService>();

// other setup omitted   
var app = builder.Build();
```

My `SettingsService` has the following constructor:

```
public SettingsService(IConfiguration configuration, Logger logger)
```

The above all works great.

I now want to create my `SettingsService` before I call `var app = builder.Build();`. I am running some HostedServices and only want to create the hosted service depending on the settings I have set on my `SettingsService` object.

How can this be done?

Comment: There's no DI container before `Build()`. Something called `Settings` is most likely part of configuration anyway, and could be created using eg `Configure`. Or it should be a configuration source itself. `only want to create the hosted service depending on the settings` the service starts when you call `app.Run` so there's no need to instantiate `SettingsService` or rather, `ServiceConfiguration` in advance. Finally, you can leave the decision to run or not to the HostedService itself - inject SettingsService  in its constructor and have `StartAsync`/`ExecuteAsync` inspect it and exit

Answer (score 0):

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
      .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
      .Build();

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var seriLog = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration).Enrich.WithExceptionDetails().Enrich.WithDemystifiedStackTraces().CreateLogger();
builder.Host.UseSerilog(seriLog);

var settingServiceLog = new SerilogLoggerFactory(seriLog).CreateLogger<SettingsService>();
var settingService = new SettingsService(configuration, settingServiceLog);

builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISettingsService>(settingService);

var app = builder.Build();
```

The above seems to work

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of searchers,

If you're instantiating a Singleton in Program.cs with a Logger using ApplicationInsights injected before `builder.Build()`, you can create a TelemetryClient that will publish to application insights.

The code looks like:

```
var tcConfig = new TelemetryConfiguration() { ConnectionString = appInsightsConnectionString };
TelemetryClient tc = new TelemetryClient(tcConfig);
ApplicationInsightsLoggerOptions options = new ApplicationInsightsLoggerOptions();
var logger = new ApplicationInsightsLogger(typeof(MySingleton).FullName, tc, options);

var instance = new MySingleton(logger);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMySingleton, MySingleton>(_ => instance);
```

Or, a shorter version:

```
// services is IServiceCollection
var logger = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<ILogger<MySingleton>>();
services.AddSingleton<IRegistrationService, RegistrationService>((x) => new MySingleton(logger));
```

This worked to inject a logger into something before `builder.Build()`.